# && unexpected token on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get this working, but the && isn't working. I'm trying to get bottombutton to display on scroll but be displayed none for everything else unless .yes == display none.

Can someone please help?

Also, how can compact code on these 3 scripts below please?

```
    <script>        
    $(window).load(function(){
    if($('.yes').css('display') == 'none')
    {
    $('#button').css('display', 'block');
    }  
    });        
    </script>

   <script>
    $(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 300) {
        $('#bottombadge').fadeIn();
        $('.bottomcta').fadeIn();
        $('.bottomandroid').fadeIn();
        $('.bottomapple').fadeIn();
        /*$('#bottombutton').fadeIn();*/ 
    } else {
        $('#bottombadge').fadeOut();
        $('.bottomcta').fadeOut();
        $('.bottomandroid').fadeOut();
        $('.bottomapple').fadeOut();
        /*$('#bottombutton').fadeOut();*/        
    }     
});
    </script>

    <script>

    $(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    **if (y > 300) && ($('.yes').css('display') == 'none'){**
    $('#bottombutton').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#bottombutton').fadeOut();        
    }      
}); 
    </script>
```

Any help is much appreciated on this. Thanks again

Comment: You've parenthesized the `if` statement incorrectly. The `if` needs an outer `( )` pair around the whole expression.

Comment: You should try to format the code better, as this is quite messy. Also, are those `**` actually part of your code?

Comment: @Carcigenicate No, this is bold-formatting which doesn’t work in code samples like this.

Comment: @Xufox Ahh, I would have used a comment to draw attention to that part instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) pointed out, your parenthesis are incorrect.

This is the correct format:

```js
if ( condition ) {
    ...
}
```

And you're doing:

```js
if (y > 300) && (something_else) {
    ...
}
```

Which is basically the same as:

```js
if (y > 300) {
    && (something_else)  // Unexpected '&&'!
}
```

To fix it, wrap it all in parenthesis:

```js
if ( (y > 300) && (something_else) ) {
    ...
}
```

---

You can also join all 3 `<script>` tags in only one, like so:

```html
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        if ($('.yes').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('#button').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (y > 300) {
            $('#bottombadge, .bottomcta, .bottomandroid, .bottomapple').fadeIn();

            if (($('.yes').css('display') == 'none')) {
                /* (y > 300) AND (display IS "none") */
                $('#bottombutton').fadeIn();
            } else {
                /* (y > 300) AND (display ISN'T "none") */
                $('#bottombutton').fadeOut();
            }
        } else {
            /* (y <= 300) */
            $('#bottombutton, #bottombadge, .bottomcta, .bottomandroid, .bottomapple').fadeOut();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigada Matheus por esclarecer! One more thing, how do I make this code a bit more neat?

Comment: De nada! I edited the question to include the answer to the second question. You had two different functions running on the `$(document).scroll()` event, so I joined them c:

Comment: Oi Matheus, muito obrigada pela ajuda! Tenho um problema agora, pq tenho um device detect, esta overwriting. Preciso que o .cta = display block mas esta being overwritten no device detect aqui:                 
   else if (isAndroid){
     $('.apple').remove(); 
              $('.android').bind();
              $('.cta').remove();
              $('.bottomcta').remove();  
              $('.bottomandroid').bind();
              $('.bottomapple').remove();
}
Como faço para que o .cta funcione aqui dentro por favor?

Comment: if (($('.yes').css('display') == 'none')) {
                /* (y > 300) AND (display IS "none") */
                $('#bottombutton').fadeIn();
            } else {
                /* (y > 300) AND (display ISN'T "none") */
                $('#bottombutton').fadeOut();
            }

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error

this:

```
if (y > 300) && ($('.yes').css('display') == 'none')
```

should be this:

```
if ((y > 300) && ($('.yes').css('display') == 'none'))
```

Comment: @xufox thanks! I think something funky happened in my editor when I was fixing that :)